# старый функционал наследуется vue router

Tags: vue.js, router

При переходе через router.push во vue работает код прошлой ссылки. В консоли вылезают ошибки. С чем может быть связано? Скорее всего, я так понимаю, я прослушивание сделал на window и он применил ко всему приложению это, но если я перейду на другую страницу и обновлю, такого же нет поведения

Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Без минимального примера сложна сказать что у вас там

Comment: Да я уже разобрался, лишь интересует, что если поставить прослушивание события на window, то как я полагаю даже при переходе будет срабатывать это событие, потому что spa?